# NHibernate or EF for existing 3 tier business layer project upgrade

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, nhibernate

I have an existing Project in asp.net which is based on 3 tier architecture with most business logic in stored procedures(About 70%).

We now have to upgrade the architecture and we are evaluating whether to use Entity Framework or nHibernate.

Could you please let me know which framework would be better to support our existing Stored procedures based business layer. Do EF or Nhibernate support directly executing queries or we will have to rewrite the entire BAL to use object classes?

Answer (score 1):

To proceed with your evaluation, you should read the NHibernate reference documentation at http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/index.html, particularly chapter 17 is relevant.

If you don't aim to switch to an object based model, I don't see why you should use ANY of NHibernate or EF, as these are intended to support an object based architecture.